# Temporary job etiquette

Tags: postdocs

My current appointment will be over in about 1.5 months, and I have been approached by a faculty member asking wether I would be interested in working (paid) on a different project for a couple of months more. After sending them my CV and relevant material, how long should I wait before asking if the opportunity exists or not? I need to arrange the practical details (housing, ...)

Comment: I don't completely understand the situation--this is a paid position?--but I don't see any reason to delay asking about practicalities if you're interested in doing it.

Comment: Yes it is a paid position.

Comment: Then yes, it's very reasonable to ask now when you'll hear a decision on it.